# Ubuntu touch support Lenovo Flex 5 14IAU7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touch

I want to install Ubuntu or a other Linux on my Laptop, the device has a touchscreen. But Ubuntu only recognises one finger, not multitouch.

I have search for drivers but Lenovo don't give us Linux drivers. Is there any way to make it work? I don't have any Ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: You should not fix this, Ubuntu should. You should report the bug.